# best way to make a knex request from inside a promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise, knex.js

knex newbie here,trying to move away from sequelize.

i am trying use a series of knex raw calls in a promise.

after much research, i came up with a simple working example, but i would like somebody with a better background in knex/promises to make any suggestions before proceeding.

```
const firstPromise = ( promiseInput )   =>      {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                console.log('parameter passed into promise: ' + promiseInput);

                knex.raw("SELECT VERSION()")
                .then(
                    (version) => {      console.log     ('inside:  ' + version[0][0]["VERSION()"] );
                                        resolve         ('outside: ' + version[0][0]["VERSION()"] );
                                }
                ).catch(
                        (err) => { reject(err); }
                )
        })
}

const secondPromise = ( input ) =>              {
        return new Promise (    (resolve, reject) => {
                resolve (input) ;
        })
}


console.log('Starting run.');

firstPromise('promise input.')
        .then(  (response)      =>      {       console.log     ('response from firstPromise: ' + response)     ;
                                                return response                                                 ;
                                        }                                                                               )
        .then(  (newResponse)   =>      console.log     ('ending! ' + newResponse)                                      )
        .then(  ()              =>      knex.destroy()                                                                  )
        .then(  ()              =>      secondPromise('stuff into second promise')
                                                .then((result) => { console.log('calling second promise: ' + result); return (result);} )       )
        .then(  (lastResponse)  =>      console.log     ('last response: ' + lastResponse)                              )
        .catch( (error)         =>      console.log     ('error! ' + error)                                             )
        ;
```

also, please let me know if this is the correct forum for such a question.

thank you for your time and consideration.

side-note:  its amazing how much easier knex is over sequelize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to create a new promise each time, that's overkill and kinda useless.
you can do:

```js
function firstPromise(promiseInput){
  console.log('parameter passed into first promise: ' + promiseInput);
  return  knex.raw("SELECT VERSION()");
}
function secondPromise(promiseInput){
  console.log('result of first promise passed into second promise: ' + promiseInput);
  return  [your knex stuff here]
}
[... other promieses]

firstPromise()
  .then(secondPromise)
  .then(thirdPromise)
  .then(console.log)
```

Your promises are all taking the result of the previous promise and returning to the next.
Also you don't need to call `knex.destroy()` because you will close the connection.

p.s. yes you can ask such questions here.

Comment: "that's overkill and kinda useless" - you are too kind!

Comment: usually newbie questions on SO tend to get downvoted for not putting in enough research.  your solution is very elegant and works perfectly.  thank you so much.